# Get the string but fail to pass it to the browser

Tags: javascript, meteor

I got a very weird question when I tried entering some texts in a textarea, pass the texts to the collection and then display the text on another page. My collection is

```
Text = new Mongo.Collection("text");
```

In the text upload template:

```
Template.textsUpload.events({
     event.preventDefault();
     var texts = $("#textUpload-id").val();
     if(Text.find({}).count() < 1){Text.insert({text : texts}}
     else{Text.update(this._id, {$set: {text : texts}}}
` })
```

On the server side:

```
if(Text.find().count() < 1){
    Text.insert({text : "No value"})
}
```

On the page to display the texts:

```
Template.result.helpers({
   display: function(){
     console.log(Text.find({}).count());
     if(Text.find({}).count() > 0){
       console.log((Text.find({}).fetch()[0].text));
       return Text.find({}).fetch()[0].text;
     }else{
        return "No value";
     }
})
```

After I entered some texts in the text area and submitted it, the console successfully showed the text I entered and the Text collection's size is 1. However, the `{{display}}` in corresponding html file always showed "No value". And if I added a:

```
console.log(Text.find({}).count())
```

in the

```
if(Text.find({}).count() > 0)
```

clause, it gave me 0.

I'm very confused now. Anyone explains a bit what is going on here?

Comment: On the server, your `if` just inserts a document with `text : "no value"` as the first document in the collection, right? So isn't `Text.find({}).fetch()[0].text` always going to be `"no value"` - because you're always inserting that first? Where/when exactly does this `if` run? Or have I missed the point?

Comment: The if is on the client side and every time I enter some texts and submit, I'll update the text with the value I entered before. By using console.log(Text.find({}).fetch()[0].text), I can see the right value in the console. But it doesn't correctly show up on the page